# Разбить множество значений на отрезки

Tags: python, list, numpy, interval

У меня есть большой лист/np.array неубывающих вещественных чисел, а также второй маленький неубывающий лист/np.array. Как разделить первый лист на n-1 частей так, чтобы второй лист задавал границы подотрезков первого листа, n -- размер второго листа. В итоговый результат должны попасть все значения из `arr1` и `arr2`, которые лежат в отрезке

`[arr1[0]; arr1[-1]]`.

Например:

```
arr1 = [0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1]

arr2 = [0, 0.3, 0.75, 1.25]
```

Желаемый результат:

```
intervals = [[0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75], [0.75, 0.8, 1]]
```

Comment: почему в результате только один `0`?

Comment: В результате в последнем списке разве не [0.75, 0.8, 1, 1.25] должно быть?

Comment: @MaxU одинаковые элементы из `arr1` и `arr2` не повторяются, но если в `arr1` самом есть одинаковые, то они повторяются

Comment: @strawdog последний элемент должен быть равен 1, потому что итоговый результата должен состоять из реальных значений, а они в `arr1` (отрезок [0;1]), `arr2` это границы, содержащие элементы возможно не встречающиеся в `arr1`

Comment: @MaxU ну и элементы `arr2` повторяются на границах этих интервалов, как видно из примера

Comment: @Валера, желаемый результат из вопроса не соответствует описанию. Поэтому не совсем понятно что вы хотите получить и по какому алгоритму...

Comment: @MaxU представьте просто отрезок числовой `[0; 1]`, `arr1` содержит неубывающую последовательность чисел из него (возможно есть повторения), `arr2` выступает в роли границ отрезков, которые должны попасть в результат. Кроме этих границ из `arr2` в результат должны попасть элементы x из `arr1` такие, что `arr2[i-1]<=x<=arr2[i]` + условие что если граница `arr2` выходит за `[0;1]` то вместо неё берется соответственно 0 или 1

Comment: по этому описанию `1.25` должен быть последним элементом последнего списка...

Comment: @MaxU да, я исправил добавленным условием

Comment: @Валера, IMO у вас слишком много "искусственных" условий для того, чтобы найти векторизированное решение...

Comment: @MaxU а какие условия минимально надо убрать, чтобы получить простое решение? Я могу изменить формат `arr1` и `arr2` так, чтобы первый и последний элементы совпадали, т.е. и там и там было `0` и `1`

Comment: @MaxU можно добавить эту зависимость

Comment: @Валера, что-то не получается у меня элегантного решения из-за искуссвенно добавленных границ интервалов из `arr2`...

Comment: Numpy позволяет эффективно работать с матрицами. То что вы хотите получить - это нечто другое. Некоторые значения из `arr2` надо брать по два раза (все кроме первого и последнего элементов) и кроме этого одинаковые значения (например `0.3`)  попадают в разные интервалы. Это значительно усложняет векторизированное / эффективное решение. Вы можете объяснить для чего вам это нужно? Мне кажется здесь имеет место [Проблема "Микроскопа-Молотка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709)

Answer (score 1):

Как уже было сказано, условия задачи не позволяют решить ее **полностью** в векторизированном формате, так что, приходится создавать некрасивые скалярные проходы:

```
import pandas as pd
```

Исходные данные:

```
arr1 = [0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 1]
arr2 = [0, 0.3, 0.75, 1.25]
```

Собственно, код:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(arr1)
grp = df.groupby(pd.cut(df[0], arr2))[0]
res = []
for k, gp in grp:
        if k.right <= arr1[-1]:
            res.append([k.left] + gp.tolist() + [k.right])
        else:
            res.append([k.left] + gp.tolist())

print(res)
```

Результат:

```
[[0.0, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3], [0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.75], [0.75, 0.8, 1.0]]
```